# Excess function and mean curvature

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

I'm reading Savin's lecture notes on nonlocal minimal surfaces (available [here](https://pabloraulstinga.github.io/Savin-lecture-notes-NSFE2022.pdf)) and he defines what he calls the excess function of a smooth set $E$ with $0\in\partial E$ by$$e(r)=\frac{\int_{\partial B_r}\chi_{E^c}-\chi_{E}\:d\sigma}{r^{n-1}}.$$
(I'm saying what he calls because there is a different notion of excess used in Geometric Measure Theory and I'm not suer whether they coincide or not.)

Then he claims that $$e(r)=c_nHr+o(r^2),\quad\text{as }r\rightarrow0$$ where $H$ is the mean curvature of $E$ at $0$ with respect to the inner normal and I can't figure out why this formula is true, rigorously or heurisitaclly.

I tried doing a Taylor expnasion of $e$ around 0 which gives $$e(r)=re'(0)+O(r^2),\quad\text{as }r\rightarrow0.$$

Now, there may be a typo in the notes so that the little $o$ is actually a big $O$, I don't know but if we believe that's the case we wind up with having to prove something like $$e'(0)=c_nH.$$ If we change variables we have that $$e'(0)=\frac{d}{dr}\left.\left(\int_{\partial B_1}\chi_{E^c}(r\sigma)-\chi_{E}(r\sigma)\:d\sigma\right)\right|_{r=0}$$ and, *formally* using the Divergence Theorem we have $$\frac{d}{dr}\left(\int_{\partial B_1}\chi_{E^c}(r\sigma)-\chi_{E}(r\sigma)\:d\sigma\right)=r\int_{\partial B_1}\nabla(\chi_{E^c}-\chi_{E})(r\sigma)\cdot\sigma\:d\sigma=r^2\int_{B_1}\Delta (\chi_{E^c}-\chi_{E})\:dx$$
and I think $\Delta (\chi_{E^c}-\chi_{E})$ is related to the mean curvature of $E$ at $0$.

This is what I got so far. Any help getting the formula rigorously or intuitive insights on why it should be true are much appretiated.

Comment: I am to lazy to do the full calculation, but I believe the following should work: Write $\partial E$ as a graph of a function $h$ around $0$, where you pick the orientation such that $h(0)=0$ and $\nabla h(0) =0$. Then up to a small error your integral is just $2\int_{\partial B_r} h$. Taylor-expand $h$ around $0$ and I believe you should end up with the highest order term being a multiple of the trace of the Hessian, i.e. the mean curvature. I think you are right about the big O though, as in this type of calculation $o(r^2)$ would immediately imply the stronger $O(r^3)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I believe the integral should be over the $(n-2)-$dimensional ball, right? That is where $h$ is defined. And I wrote down the computation and you do get the little $o$ of $r^2$. Now I am left with proving rigorously that the integral is what you said it is. I gues that in small balls we can count on some cancellation of the set and its complement and you wind up with what is on the boundary.

Comment: Sorry, sphere not ball...

Comment: Yes, the sphere is one dimension less. The integral is actually quite easy using symmetries. All you have in the Taylor-expansion are terms of the form $\partial_{ij} h(0) x_i x_j$, so you only need to integrate $x_i x_j$. For $i \neq j$ this is an odd function in $x_i$, so since the domain is symmetric, the integral of that term is $0$. For $i=j$ it is even and positive a.e., so the integral will be some positive constant, which for symmetry is independent of $i$. Summing up then gives you $c \Delta h(0)$.

Comment: Yes, that integral is fine. I ment proving that $e(r)=2\int_{\partial B'_r}h+\text{error}$, that's where I guess some kind of cancellation should give that you only have the integral on $\partial B'_r$ since the other parts should "balance out".

Comment: Well, the details of that are precisely why I did not do the full calculation. But note that $\chi_E$ and $\chi_{E^C}$ sum up to one, so adding their sum to the integrand just adds a sphere area, resp. two half spheres. So the integral is equal to $2 \int_{\partial B_r} \chi_{E^c} - \chi_{H} d\sigma$, where $H$ is the half-space "outside" at $0$. So the integral measures the signed area on $\partial B_r$ between the intersection with $\partial E$ and the equator. Now if $r$ is small, this deflection is tiny and the sides of the sphere are vertical, so we get the integral of $h$ on the equator.

Comment: That's  very nice, thank you!